# How to select the html element with same class name?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to select the second div with class="editor-col", but the element that i get is in the second div in first div with class="editor-col".

**C# code:**

```
/*Create and initialize object*/
IWebElement dropdown_priority = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.k-edit-form-container div:nth-child(2)")); //select issue tab
```

**HTML element:**

```
<div class="k-edit-form-container">
   <div class="editor-label"></div>
   <div class="editor-label"></div>
   <div class="editor-label"></div>
</div>
```

Apreciate your advice on how to select the second div with class="editor-col". Thanks.

Comment: You should put your code as a text, not as image.

Comment: Please share your code in text

Comment: @Alex Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks. I will update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U find all divs with same class and use index to get 2nd of em

```
By.XPath(".//div[@class='editor-col'][1]")
```